# loop itextsharp content to create new page in same pdf based on sql item

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, pdf, itext

I am creating a pdf document with fields  from sql database using iTextsharp,when a client inputs information each page is saved in new row with page01,page02 etc as a column within that database. I would like iTextsharp to loop and create a new page based on this page number

```
    protected void GenerateReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dr = GetData("SELECT * FROM OnSiteWorkTx where DocID = " + DropDownListPdf.SelectedItem.Value).Rows[0]; ;
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
        Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            Phrase phrase = null;
            PdfPCell cell = null;
            PdfPTable table = null;
            BaseColor color = null;

            document.Open();

    table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.SetWidths(new float[] { 2f, 10f });
            table.TotalWidth = 480f;
            table.LockedWidth = true;
            table.SpacingBefore = 15f;
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;


            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk("doc 018/2\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            phrase.Add(new Chunk("On Site Work                        " + "Visit " + dr["VisitNumber"] + "   " + dr["PageNumber"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            // table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("On Site Work", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 20, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 13f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Company: ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Company"] + "          " + "           " + "          " + "           " + "           " + "           " + "           " + "Email: " + dr["Email"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 7;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Plant: ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Plant"] + "          " + "           " + "          " + "           " + "           " + "           " + "          " + "Contact Tel: " + dr["ContactTel"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Contact Person: ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["ContactPerson"] + "          " + "           " + "          " + "           " + "           " + "           " + "Fax No: " + dr["FaxNo"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 160f, document.PageSize.Width - 30f, document.Top - 160f, BaseColor.BLACK);
            document.Add(table);

            table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.SetWidths(new float[] { 2f, 10f });
            table.TotalWidth = 480f;
            table.LockedWidth = true;
            table.SpacingBefore = 15f;
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;


            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Actuator Type: ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["ActuatorType"] + "     " + "Drive: " + dr["Drive"] + "           " + "           " + "Matic Type: " + dr["MATICTYPE"] + "     " + "Control: " + dr["CONTROL"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Comm No: ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["CommNo"] + "         " + "          " + "          " + "           " + "           " + "Matic Comm No: " + dr["MATICCOMMNO"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

    document.Add(table);

                document.Close();

                byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();
                Response.Clear();

                MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("email", txt_To.Text);
                mm.CC.Add(txt_Cc.Text);
                mm.Subject = txt_Subject.Text;
                mm.Body = txt_Message.Text;
                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "OnSiteWork.pdf"));
                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = "email";
                NetworkCred.Password = "password";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Send(mm);
```

Comment: You'll have to rephrase your question because right now it doesn't make sense. You create a table and add it to the document. If the table fits the page, the document only takes one page. If the table doesn't fit, the table is split and distributed over multiple pages. If you want two tables on a separate page, you add `doc.newPage()` between two `doc.add(table)` statements. Your requirement "I would like iTextsharp to loop and create a new page based on this page number" assumes that people on SO know what you're talking about. What is *this page number* in that sentence? What is *each page*?

Comment: the Page number is a column in the row, I have added a column visit number, this visit number will be the same in say three rows if the user presses next three times. I think i need a query to go through the database row by row and if visit number is the same it must get data from  the next row and insert into the pdf so doc.NewPage(); shoud be before the query so it automatically puts the info on new page  if not then doc.close it prints the pdf.

I hope i am making sense

Comment: "the page number is a column in the row": which row? A field in a database record? A cell in a column? "I have added a column visit number": what is a column visit number? "if the user presses next three times": what is the user pressing? I'm sorry, but you really should get your act together and explain your requirement in terms that are easy to understand for somebody who doesn't know your project: please rewrite your question or it will be closed.